# selecting distinct values of an html attribute with xpath

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to select the `reference` value, and some other values (e.g. `delivery_out_of_stock`) from this code with `xpath` (or `css` if it's better).

Any suggestion on how to approach it?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="product-details" data-product="{"id_shop_default":"1","id_manufacturer":"993","id_supplier":"0","reference":"0165926","is_virtual":"0","delivery_in_stock":"","delivery_out_stock":"","id_category_default":"1006","on_sale":"0","online_only":"0","ecotax":0,"minimal_quantity":"1","low_stock_threshold":null}" role="tabpanel">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to get the value of the "reference" key?

Comment: Updated text for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I would use xpath to get the data in data-product, and then load the json as a dictionary to find the values you need:

```
import json
# xpath to get the data in data-product
data_product = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-details"]/@data-product').extract_first()
# load the json in a dictionary
data = json.loads(data_product)
# get the value by key
reference = data['refererce']
delivery_out_of_stock = data['delivery_out_of_stock']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, css is better. I recommend downloading selector gadget extension for chrome for getting the values you want from a page.